# Switch graphic driver of virtual box's ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, opengl, virtual-machine, virtualbox, catalyst

I would like to use fglrx on my virtual box run ubuntu. Indeed i need it to be able to use OpenGL4 on my virtual box (my mac book pro is able to use opengl4 but it stuck at 2.1) so that's the goal of this question. Actually my virtual machine is stuck at openGL 3.3 and i can't upgrade.
If they are other way to get opengl4 tell me please.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? What VM and version? Both may have limitations on the GPU driver version available.

Comment: It's ubuntu 16.04 LTS (64 bit) , what is the vm ?

Comment: VM: Virtual Machine. It seems you VM is VirtualBox.

Comment: the vm is virtual box 5.1.22

Comment: What `glxinfo` (run it in the VM)  says about your driver and OGL version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to use fglrx on my virtual box run ubuntu

Does your VirtualBox have a AMD Radeon/FireGL GPU? If no, then what purpose would `fglrx` serve?

> Actually my virtual machine is stuck at openGL 3.3 and i can't upgrade.

Update to the very latest of Mesa and use software rasterzation. Or pass through a GPU which supports OpenGL-4 and pass throgh that.

Comment: My Mac Gpu is a "Intel Iris Graphics" wich is suppose to support opengl4 according to https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202823 (mid2014 macbook pro) so i suppose that it the same for my virtual box. I already update mesa which is mesa 17.0.7 and my core profile is still 3.3.

Comment: I thought that install fglrx permite me to use opengl4 if it's not the case i'm sorry i'm a kind of nooby in virtual computing.

Comment: @ValentinMercier: `fglrx` is the proprietary graphics/OpenGL driver develeoped by AMD for their GPUs.

Comment: ok my mistake then , do you know how could i set my core to opengl4 ?

Comment: I think you misunderstood what "core" and "compatibility" mean with respect to OpenGL: *core profiles* are OpenGL feature sets that must be supported. *compatibility profiles* are optional and may not be available (so far only the proprietary drivers of Nvidia and AMD for Windows and Linux do support compatibility profiles at all). Which version of OpenGL is supported ultimately comes down to the installed GPU/graphics card. You can install a pure software implementation like Mesa llvm/softpipe. But the usual approach is to upgrade the GPU.

Comment: @ValentinMercier: Upgrading the GPU in a notebook is not really possible. But if the notebook does have a Thunderbolt port or Express Card slot you can install a desktop GPU in an external enclosure that connects to Thunderbolt or Express Card (technically you can even connect to a Mini-PCIe slot on the mainboard, if such a slot is available).

Comment: I already update my gpu software (it's include in the os update) and i'm still stuck on 3.3 on my virtual machine even if i have mesa 17.07 on ubuntu :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153705/discussion-between-valentin-mercier-and-datenwolf).